# How to write Custom HTML code for a Rally/CA report

Tags: report, rally

What would be the HTML code to "filter out" a handful of specific user stories?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is highly unspecific. The only way to get stories is to programatically access the API via a language like Javascript, Java, C#, C++, etc., etc.

You can embed javascript into your html page and get the code to fetch stories with a filter passed in on the access. To see how to structure a query, you could turn on the developer tools in your browser and have a look at the network accesses that the browser does when fetching stories into a custom list app on a page. Using the custom list, you could refine your query to what you want first.

Answer (score 0):

You could always build a custom app for a specific use case, but if you're looking for data and having trouble finding it, there are ways to do so with a combination of custom lists, Rally's own query language, and creative use of advanced filters. It's also possible to massage your data in way that makes Rally's native reporting a bit easier to use.

This is just an example but, if I'm looking to get information on the quarterly progress of my team who don't use start/end date or releases/milestones, there's not a lot available from an app/report standpoint that's already built. However, if I coach my team on keeping a few simple data elements neat and tidy, and utilize the custom report views to make that data useful, it can be pretty quick and easy to implement.

I have my teams keep a few basic fields up to date: Title, Owner, Project, Tags, Refined Estimate (all at a feature level), and most importantly - keeping a parent/child relationship between most work.

Now I can build a report that filters by a certain tag, that can also be filtered by team, and also has the ability to show additional valuable data that can be unearthed because your house is tidy. In this case, you can now display a column that will total all child objects under a certain feature, and display that next to 'Planned' estimate, which will give you the ability to also export and show a planned vs. actual to help your teams estimate more accurately.

It's a round-about way of saying there are a lot of possibilities with the tool if you can use your resources. Building custom apps means you also have to maintain them or pay someone with the knowledge to do so.